# Handling a function where the return might (or might not) be async

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function. It doesn't work, but the idea is that if a `sessionStorage` variable is already set, use it. If not, make a call to the API and then set the `sessionVariable` for next time.

```
isAdmin: function() {

    // hit the first page, or refreshed.
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("isAdministrator") === null) {
        AzureGroupService.get({adGroup: "Programmers"}).$promise.then(function (data) {
            sessionStorage["isAdministrator"] === data.isMember;
            return data.isMember;
        });
    }
    else {
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage["isAdministrator"]);
    }
}
```

So the function might return immediately, or it might need to wait on the API. Is this even close to the right way to do this?

If so, how would I call it in a controller? Something like this?

```
user.isAdmin().then(function(response) {
    vm.test = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $q.when() , if the sessionStorage object is not null. Your isAdmin() function should look like this.

```
isAdmin: function() {

// hit the first page, or refreshed.
if(sessionStorage.getItem("isAdministrator") === null) {
    return AzureGroupService.get({adGroup: "Programmers"}).$promise.then(function (data) {
        sessionStorage["isAdministrator"] === data.isMember;
        return data.isMember;
    });
}
else {
    return $q.when(JSON.parse(sessionStorage["isAdministrator"]));
}
}
```

Your controller should look like this , isAdmin() function will always return a promise . So u can define a success callback using .then().

```
user.isAdmin().then(function(response) {
    vm.test = response.data;
});
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I did have to make one small change though. I think it should be `return $q.when(JSON.parse(sessionStorage["isAdministrator"]));` Note the return.

Comment: No need to return

Comment: If I don't return, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined." Going from my limited understanding of the situation, I think that make sense. `user.isAdmin().then(function(response)` is expecting a promise. Without the return, there isn't one.

Comment: Ohh my mistake. Didnt check it, I will edit the answer

Comment: I appreciate the answer. It really helped.